# How to call a php function in HTML

Tags: php, html

Rookie here, so please correct me if I have anything wrong.

So here's a snippet of my HTML:

```
<html><body>
<h2>Home Page</h2>
Welcome back <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!
</body></html>
```

The function, $fgmembersite->UserFullName(), returns a string (100%, if I call the function within  tags it prints out correctly).  How do I get it to echo out in the HTML?

I think an alternative would be to echo the entire HTML code, and I think it'd work then, but I don't want to do it that way because I read somewhere that echoing all of your HTML is bad.  Could somebody also confirm/deny that?

Right now, this is what shows on the site:
**Welcome back UserFullName(); ?>!**

No idea why

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What happens when you use `<?php echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>`?

Comment: You need to keep the `<?= ... ?>` (or `<?php echo ... ?>`) surrounding the code itself.

Comment: I'm also relatively new to stackoverflow, why would you add a comment instead of post an answer?

Comment: This is because short tags are not "on". @MattyAyOh

Comment: what are 'short tags' haha sorry

Comment: This => http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php @MattyAyOh

Comment: The reason it's a comment instead of an answer is that it was intended to gather more data. The real answer is @Fred-ii- comment, and my comment highlighted that. To be fair, though, it's common to have them disabled and using the longer syntax is often the way to go.

Comment: Okay, I get it, thanks @ctrahey

Is it possible to close this question?  I didn't expect so many answers so quickly and I think I angered people because my post has negative points -.-

Comment: Heh. I think you've just caught SO on a moody morning. Personally, I think this is the kind of question that makes SO so valuable for folks new to programming. Best of luck!

Comment: @MattyAyOh Nah, I doubt "angered" would be it (*wouldn't be right anyway*). Many expect other people to know all this type of stuff, as if it were embedded in our DNA at birth. I for one, have also "been there"; everyone needs to start from somewhere. Welcome to the wonderful world of coding, enjoy. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the result of the *browser* trying to parse the PHP. It is trying to treat `<?= $fgmembersite->` as an unknown tag and then renders the rest as text.

There are two possible reasons for this:

---

You need to pass it through a PHP engine first.

You need to access the file through a web server which supports PHP and is configured to run your file through PHP when it is requested (typically this is done by using a `.php` file extension).

Note that installing a web server then double clicking a PHP file in your file manager isn't sufficient - the browser will just load the file from the file system. You need to type `http://etc etc`.

---

It is also possible that you have [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) disabled (which is common and sensible) and are using PHP 5.3 or older (which isn't a great idea, 5.3 is still supported but it is the oldest branch that is).

If this is the case, your options are:

- Upgrade PHP
- Use `<?php echo ... ?>` instead of `<?= ... ?>`
- Enable `short_open_tag`

Comment: the file extension is .php,
is that what you meant by pass through a php engine?
(pardon my ignorance)

Comment: @MattyAyOh — See the third and fourth paragraphs of the answer.

Comment: Yup it is the short_open_tag thing.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the code to look like this...

```
Welcome back <?php echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!
```

This will ECHO the result of the function call.

Comment: `<?=` is equivalent to `<?php echo`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do

```
<?php echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>
```

?

Comment: He is. `<?=` is equivalent to `<?php echo`.

Comment: Obviously, short tags are not on. @Quentin See the comments under OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

use it as follows:

```
<html><body>
<h2>Home Page</h2>
Welcome back <?php echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!
</body></html>
```

Comment: He is. `<?=` is equivalent to `<?php echo`.

Comment: @Quentin the short-tags behavior depends on configuration, echo does not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) enabled on your server? You need to have that enabled to use that syntax. If you don't have that, use `<?php echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>` like the other users suggested.

You can check the setting on you server by creating a file containing `<?php phpinfo();` in it, and accessing that.

Also, echoing all your HTML inside the `<?php` tags are considered a bad practice because you should separate your business logic and your HTML. Echoing HTML directly from inside the PHP tags quickly leads to a mix of HTML and PHP, and it will be harder to read (for others, and yourself later on)

Comment: Doesn't `short_open_tag` only influence `<?` not `<?=`?

Comment: Yes, from PHP 5.4 and up.